# ANOVA Table with different number of observations per treatment R

Tags: r, anova

I am trying to create an Anova table in R with data where there are a different number of observations per treatment, but I only know how to do this with equal number of observations for all treatments. Any help would be appreciated.

After setting up my data set, I have tried using:

```
> tmA=tm = gl(k, 1, nA*k, factor("A")) 
> tmB=tm = gl(k, 1, nB*k, factor("B")) 
> tmC=tm = gl(k, 1, nC*k, factor("C")) 
#nA, nB, nC represent number of observations per treatment for treatments A, B, C respectively 
tm=c(tmA, tmB, tmC, tmD, tmE)
av=aov(r ~ tm)
```

But I get an error because variable lengths differ for tm

```
> tmA=tm = gl(k, 1, nA*k, factor("A")) 
> tmB=tm = gl(k, 1, nB*k, factor("B")) 
> tmC=tm = gl(k, 1, nC*k, factor("C")) 
#nA, nB, nC represent number of observations per treatment for                  
treatments A, B, C respectively 
tm=c(tmA, tmB, tmC, tmD, tmE)
av=aov(r ~ tm)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = r ~ tm, drop.unused.levels =      
TRUE) : 
variable lengths differ (found for 'tm')
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please give a minimal reproducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this answer, let's assume that `rA`, `rB`, and `rC` are three vectors. `rA` contains the observations of treatment A, `rB` contains the observations of treatment B, and `rC` contains the observations of treatment C.

Thus, you can do the following:

```
Data <- data.frame(
   Y=c(rA, rB, rC),
   treatment = factor(rep(c("treatA", "treatB", "treatC"), 
   times=c(length(rA), length(rB), length(rC))))
)
```

Then, you can perform an ANOVA with this new data frame.

```
anv <- aov(Y~treatment, data=Data)
anova(anv)
```